# store date picker value in database

Tags: php, database, date, datepicker, insert

I am trying to store the value of the date picker in my database. so far, i have been able to store the other values but not the date picker value.

Form:

```
                  <form class="form-signin" name="Register_Form" method="post" action="regcheck.php">
                    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>

                    <label for="SecondName" class="sr-only">Second Name</label>
                    <input type="SecondName" id="SecondName" name="SecondName" class="form-control" placeholder="Second Name" required>

                    <div class="input-group input-append date" id="dateRangePicker"> <!-- Date input -->
                        <label for="Course" class="sr-only">Date</label>
                   <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                    </div>

                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="reg" name="reg" value="Register">Register</button>
                  </form>
```

code to insert into database:

```
            require_once 'connect.php';
            if (isset($_POST['reg'])){ 
                        $dob = $_POST['date'];
                        $Student_ID = $_POST['Student_ID'];
                        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
                        $course = $_POST['Course'];
                        $email = $_POST['inputEmail'];
                        $password = $_POST['inputPassword'];
                        $FN = $_POST['FirstName'];
                        $SN = $_POST['SecondName']; 

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblaccounts (Email, Password, Student_ID, FirstName, SecondName, Course, Gender, DoB) VALUES ('".$email."','".$password."','".$Student_ID."','".$FN."','".$SN."','".$course."','".$gender."','".$dob."')"; 
                    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Database Connection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
                    //$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                    echo "Registeration Successful!:";  

                    header('Location: login.php');
            } else { 
                        echo "Registeration Failed!:";# 
                        ?><br/><a href ="login.php">Go back to the login screen.</a><?php
                    }
            ?>
```

Comment: What is the datatype set to for your `DoB` column?

Answer (score 0):

what format is the DOB field in the DB?
If it's timestamp, then you need to do

```
$dob = strtotime($_POST['date']);
```

If it's date then you need to do

```
$dob = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date']));
```

If it's datetime, then you need to do

```
$dob = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($_POST['date']));
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql date type you can't store date like `MM/DD/YYYY` you have to change the date format to `YYYY-MM-DD`. change input like

```
$dob = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date']));
```

Comment: Using `'Y-m-d'`, whould not result in `YYYY/MM/DD`, it would result in `YYYY-MM-DD`. You'd want to use `'Y/m/d'` to result in `YYYY/MM/DD`. Just saying.